# Where is the microphone for Siri for the iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, siri, microphone

I thought it was at the bottom left on the phone, but when I cover the bottom and blow on the earpiece, the waveform when Siri is waiting for a response moves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three microphones on the iPhone 5. This setup is used to eliminate background noise while on call. One is ideally placed at the back, and two in the front. So basically when you're covering the bottom, the mic on the ear piece picks up the audio input.

[image]

Comment: Ahh, which one should I talk to Siri with? Sometimes I lift the phone up a certain way by habit. Sometimes it's noisy and the dictation is bad.

Comment: @Chloe The bottom one would be the ideal choice.

Comment: Apparently there is an accelerometer that detects which microphone it should be recording from, so that as you rotate your phone, it switches to different microphones. We had accidentally covered the back microphone with a skin, and so when the phone was rotated a specific way, the audio would cut out.

Answer (score -2):

It is part of the top mic, camera and proximity unit.